# Создание ссылок TextView на Android

Tags: java, android, textview

помогите с созданием ссылок TextView пожалуйста, перепробовал много вариантов никакой не помогает, выходит ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException

пробовал эти варианты:

1) добавить слушателя

```
    texttest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Uri adress= Uri.parse("www.google.ru");
            Intent browser= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, adress);
            startActivity(browser);
        }

    });
```

2)

```
TextView clickableTextLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_About);
    clickableTextLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

3)  Этот способ работает, но не получается создать ссылку вида

`<a href="google.ru.ru">Google</a>`

```
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Адрес: google.ru"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/texttest" />
```

Comment: все что написано тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877595/i-want-text-view-as-a-clickable-link сделал не помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сложный способ позволяющий не только сделать ссылки кликабельными, но и отловить нажатие на них:

1. Берём обычный `TextView`:

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="14dp"
       android:id="@+id/texttest" />
   ```
2. Создаём класс для обработки нажатий на ссылки в тексте:

   ```
   public class MakeLinksClicable
   {
       private final static String LOG = MakeLinksClicable.class.getSimpleName();

       public static class CustomerTextClick extends ClickableSpan
       {
           String mUrl;

           public CustomerTextClick(String url)
           {
               mUrl = url;
           }

           @Override
           public void onClick(View widget)
           {
               //Тут можно как-то обработать нажатие на ссылку
               //Сейчас же мы просто открываем браузер с ней
               Log.i(LOG, "url clicked: " + this.mUrl);

               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               i.setData(Uri.parse(mUrl));
               widget.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
       }

       public static SpannableStringBuilder reformatText(CharSequence text)
       {
           int end = text.length();
           Spannable sp = (Spannable) text;
           URLSpan[] urls = sp.getSpans(0, end, URLSpan.class);
           SpannableStringBuilder style = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
           for (URLSpan url : urls)
           {
               style.removeSpan(url);
               MakeLinksClicable.CustomerTextClick click = new MakeLinksClicable.CustomerTextClick(url.getURL());
               style.setSpan(click, sp.getSpanStart(url), sp.getSpanEnd(url),
                       Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
           }

           return style;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Присваиваиваем `TextView` текст, указав ему, что он в HTML формате и кликабельный и ловим клики на ссылки с помощью класса из предыдущего пункта:

   ```
   TextView textView = ... //находим TextView 
   //Экранируем кавычки в атрибуте html тега слэшем:
   String textWithLink = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>";
   //Указываем с помощью Html.fromHtml, что у нас не просто текст:
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textWithLink, null, null));
   ////Указываем что разрешаем ссылки кликать:
   textView.setLinksClickable(true);
   textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
   //Научаемся отлавливать клики пропустив текст через наш класс из пред. пункта.
   CharSequence text = textView.getText();
   if (text instanceof Spannable)
   {
       textView.setText(MakeLinksClicable.reformatText(text));
   }
   ```

**Итого:**

Ссылка в `TextView` окрасится дефолтным цветом выделения ссылок, а при нажатии на неё в логи выведется адрес и запустится браузер с этой ссылкой.

**UPD_0:**

1. Чтобы дополнить вопрос - нажмите "править" - см. скриншот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Если заявленная в вопросе проблема решена - вопрос надо отметить верным, нажав на "галочку" слева от тела вопроса.
3. Если в процессе решения родился новый вопрос - задавайте новый вопрос отдельным постом на сайте. Смысл сайта: один вопрос - один ответ.

Comment: я сделал как вы сказали, но ошибка осталась (

Comment: @java, какая ошибка и где?

Comment: как я вас понял в коде textView то что у вас это у меня mytextView и textToSet это string example = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>"; да?

Comment: вот ошибка java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.by_em.gradecalculator/ru.by_em.gradecalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException, ругается на строчку  mytextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textWithLink, null, null));

Comment: @java, да, `textView` - это TextView. `textToSet` - это  неправильно скопипастил, посмотрите обновлённый ответ. У вас NPE ошибка, означающая, что вы не инициализировали `TextView`. Проверьте, что вы его правильно нашли в разметке.

Comment: все сделал так же ошибка((( вот скрин ошибки пожалуйста помогите https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4qFiSLVLNg6q/error.PNG

Comment: @java, как я уже и написал вы не инициализировали (или неправильно инициализировали) текстовое поле. Дополните вопрос кодом из `onCreate()` и мы вам скажем, где вы ошиблись.

Comment: TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texttest); //находим TextView
        String textWithLink = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>";
//Указываем с помощью Html.fromHtml, что у нас не просто текст:
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textWithLink, null, null));
        textView.setLinksClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        CharSequence text = textView.getText();
        if (text instanceof Spannable)
        {
            textView.setText(MakeLinksClicable.reformatText(text));
        }

Comment: это? и как правильно добавлять код тут)

Comment: @java, у вас с разметке активити точно есть `TextView` с таким id? Вы точно нужную разметку в `setContentView` загрузили? Вы `TextView` после  `setContentView` ищите? И  `setContentView` точно после `super.onCreate()` написано? А код надо не в комменты а через `редактировать` снизу от тела вопроса.

Comment: да точно есть, в setContentView(R.layout.main) так а texttest находится в другой разметке, и ошибка появляется после добавления кода то что вы дали, я много разных вариантов испробовал не работают на всех вариантах одна и таже ошибка

Comment: @java, `TextView` c id `texttest` должно находится в разметке активити, кою вы загружаете в `setContentView`. Т.е. в файле `res/layout/main.xml`

Comment: а как мне обратиться к другому активити или так нельзя?

Comment: @java, манипулировать одним активити из другого - невозможно. И не нужно.

Comment: я сделал как вы сказали, создал новый бланк активити и новом появившемся классе написал код ваш, запустилось без ошибок, но не работает все равно(, в новом xml файле то что создался автоматически добавил TextView и при запуске открывается пустое активити без текста

Comment: @java, а вы id прописали этому `TextView`?

Comment: <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textView_About"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

Comment: @java, ну так у вас id теперь другой... Вы по нему ищете?

Comment: да по новому(((

Comment: я в итоге хочу этот новый xml файл то что создался вставить в AlertDialog? точнее создать кастомный AlertDialog

Comment: @java, ну а если просто `textView.setText("text");` без всего остального - он хоть отобразится?.. А про диалоги - там просто надо получать `view` диалога и в нём вьюхи искать, а не в активити.

Comment: ваш код работает ))))))))) это у меня теперь диалог не правильно работает((

Comment: View myView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.about, null); //имя кастомной xml

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setView(myView);
                    builder.setTitle("About");
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_black_24dp);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);

Comment: builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //action to do
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
                    alert.show();

Comment: вот AlertDialog извините что код так кидаю не нашел как вставить), мой AlertDialog берет пустой xml почему так(

Comment: @java См. обновлённый ответ. Вместо `View.inflate` попробуйте так `getLayoutInflater().inflate`. Искать текстовое поле в диалоге надо так: `TextView tvTime = (TextView) dialog.getWindow().findViewById(
          R.id.tvTime);`

Comment: если не затруднит подробнее можно что в моем коде заменить и на что, я новичок только изучаю)

Comment: @java, создайте новый вопрос про нахождение `TextView` в `AlertDialog` с кастомной разметкой, приведите там свой код, опишите проблему, приведите логи ошибки и строчку на коей она появляется - и вам ответят и расскажут.

Answer (score 4):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Адрес: www.google.ru"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/texttest" />
```

Весь код выкиньте оставьте только разметку.

И все.

Comment: просто как мне скрыть тут ссылку чтоб осталось только название и при нажатие на название перешел по введенному адресу ?

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=http://www.google.com><font color=#AAA>Your Text</font></a>"));
```

Comment: не помогло, подчеркивается красным цветом как ошибка

Comment: @java, учитесь отлаживать код и искать причины "подчеркивания красным цветом как ошибка", автор забыл кавычки, а вы не смогли увидеть этого! Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Забыли добавить TextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());